# Bookmarklet i'm making is somehow performing document.write though its not in the code

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to write a bookmarklet that toggles the ability to make any text on the page editable, but when I execute it, it seems to be performing something along the lines of `document.write('off')`. Here's the code/bookmarklet:

```js
javascript: if (document.body.contentEditable == "true") {
  document.body.contentEditable = "true";
  document.designMode = 'on';
} else {
  document.body.contentEditable = "false";
  document.designMode = "off"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try an IIFE

```js
javascript:(function(){if (document.body.contentEditable == "true") {
  document.body.contentEditable = "true";
  document.designMode = 'on';
} else {
  document.body.contentEditable = "false";
  document.designMode = "off"
}})()
```